# Visual Studio Project on Windows 10

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

Not sure Why I am Unable to configure a Project on Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017, the Project works fine with Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 7.

Possibly I suspect TypeScript version is causing the issues.

Below are few of the errors

- Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
     Error    TS2415  (TS) Class 'Alert' incorrectly extends base class 'Dialog'.
       Types of property 'options' are incompatible.
         Type 'AlertOptions' is not assignable to type 'DialogOptions'.
           Types of property 'messages' are incompatible.
             Type 'AlertMessages' has no properties in common with type 'DialogMessages'.
- Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
     Error    TS2417  (TS) Class static side 'typeof Alert' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof Dialog'.
       Types of property 'fn' are incompatible.
         Type 'Alert' is not assignable to type 'Dialog'.
           Types of property 'options' are incompatible.
             Type 'AlertOptions' is not assignable to type 'DialogOptions'.   ComparisonSuite.Web F:\Projects\FibreCompare\12Sep2018\mithunbose-comparison-suite-v2-e1c9a921390a\ComparisonSuite.Web\Scripts\typings\kendo\kendo-ui.d.ts  1551    Active
- Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
     Error        Build:Class static side 'typeof Confirm' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof
  Dialog'. ComparisonSuite.Web F:\Projects\FibreCompare\12Sep2018\mithunbose-comparison-suite-v2-e1c9a921390a\ComparisonSuite.Web\Scripts\typings\kendo\kendo-ui.d.ts  2056
- Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
     Error        Build:Class 'Confirm' incorrectly extends base class 'Dialog'.  ComparisonSuite.Web F:\Projects\FibreCompare\12Sep2018\mithunbose-comparison-suite-v2-e1c9a921390a\ComparisonSuite.Web\Scripts\typings\kendo\kendo-ui.d.ts  2056
- Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
     Error        Build:Class static side 'typeof Prompt' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof
  Dialog'. ComparisonSuite.Web F:\Projects\FibreCompare\12Sep2018\mithunbose-comparison-suite-v2-e1c9a921390a\ComparisonSuite.Web\Scripts\typings\kendo\kendo-ui.d.ts  5184

Answer (score 0):

The errors you posted look like they come from [this issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/19319).  Try upgrading your `kendo-ui` type declarations.  If you add more information to the question about how you are currently managing your type declarations, I may be able to provide more information about how to upgrade them.

Comment: Hi Matt, I am new to kendo-ui rather to typescript and not sure how it works. The existing project is working fine on Windows 7 with Visual Studio 2015. The only issue what I suspect is typescript version on my New System with Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2017. Typescript Version 2.1 is not there on my system. I tried installing typescript 2.1 but still no success.

Comment: I have no experience managing TypeScript projects in Visual Studio, but if you'd be interested in going on a call with me and sharing your screen, I can try to help you figure out how to upgrade the type declarations.  If you're interested, please contact me on Skype (username hashproduct) and suggest some times that work for you, or give me your timezone and I'll suggest some times that work for me.  (I'm on UTC-4.)

Comment: Thanks, that's cool. I have send you an invite over skype from username rimrohit . Please ping me on skype once you are comfortable, my time zone is (UTC +5:30).